# In R, my map is getting cut off before the limits I set, how do I fix this problem?

Tags: r

[image]My polygon is getting cut off before my limit on ggplot. I have tried using the gSimplify and fortify, and without and it doesn't work.

```
#code to make the maps
canada <- raster::getData('GADM', country = 'CAN', level = 1)
ns <- subset(canada, HASC_1 == "CA.NS")
nb<-subset(canada, HASC_1 == "CA.NB")
ns <- gSimplify(ns, tol = 0.02, topologyPreserve = T)
ns <- fortify(ns) 

#plotting code
alltracks<-ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(ns, mapping = aes(long, lat, group = group), fill = "grey70")+
  geom_polygon(nb, mapping = aes(long, lat, group = group))+
  ylim(42.5,45)+
  xlim(-68,-65)
```

I also get this error: "Regions defined for each Polygons"